# Retrieving Videos from Youtube and searching/categorizing

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

Currently I am trying to pull videos from a youtube channel with youtube api and then using javascript to search and categorize it. I can get a search to work on an html table, but can't get it to work on the table I'm creating through the api.

My current html code is just basically this:

```
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
    <h1> RBx Youtube Videos </h1>
     <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Type to search">
    <table id="results"> </table>
    </div>

</body>
```

The videos are retrieved here:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
$.get(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels",{
        part: "contentDetails",
        forUsername: channelName,
        key: pkey},
        function(data){
            $.each(data.items, function(i, item){
                console.log(item);
                pid = item.contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads;
                getVids(pid);
            })
        }
);

function getVids(pid){

    $.get(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems",{
        part: "snippet",
        maxResults: 50,
        playlistId: pid,
        key: pkey},
        function(data){
            var output;
            $.each(data.items, function(i, item){
                console.log(item);
                videoTitle = item.snippet.title;
                videoId = item.snippet.resourceId.videoId;
                videoDescription=item.snippet.description;

                output = '<tr><td><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/'+videoId+'/1.jpg"></img></td><td><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='+videoId+'">'+videoTitle+'</a></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2" align="right">'+videoDescription+'<hr>';

                //output = '<tr><td>'+videoTitle+'</td></tr>';

                //Append to results listStyleType
                $('#results').append(output);
            })
        }
);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that the values of variables you use in your output string are valid. Please pay attention to the correctness of your HTML syntax in the output string. The `<img>` element must not have a closing tag as it is an empty element, and you should end your string with `</td></tr>`:

```
output = '<tr><td><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/'+videoId+'/1.jpg"></td><td><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='+videoId+'">'+videoTitle+'</a></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2" align="right">'+videoDescription+'<hr></td></tr>';
```

In general, this way of generating HTML is risky and error-prone. You should *always* validate, clean up, or escape all variables used in the output. Perhaps it can be of help to take a look at the `<template>` element introduced in HTML5, and make use of it in this kind of situations. You can check [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) using table rows.